# Syntax error in JOIN operation when executing query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database

```
string sel = "SELECT NAAM, PLAATS, tblAfstanden.AFSTAND 
                FROM tblInschrijvingen 
                INNER JOIN tblAfstanden 
                    ON tblInschrijvingen.AFSTAND = tblAfstandenID.AFSTAND";
```

Hello guys! I'm having a problem with the query above.

It gives following error:

> 'Syntax error in JOIN operation'

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: No other information at all? Hmm...

Comment: There is nothing visibly wrong with the SQL statement itself.  The error must be somewhere else in your code, so there is no way to help without seeing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's a simple typo: do you really have a table called `tblAfstandenID`?

Should it just be this:

`"SELECT NAAM, PLAATS, tblAfstanden.AFSTAND 
                FROM tblInschrijvingen 
                INNER JOIN tblAfstanden 
                    ON tblInschrijvingen.AFSTAND = tblAfstanden.AFSTAND"`

Answer (score 0):

Do below:

```
string sel = "SELECT NAAM, PLAATS, A.AFSTAND FROM tblInschrijvingen I
              INNER JOIN tblAfstanden A ON A.AFSTAND = I.AFSTAND";
```

Your syntax has error. Because in reality in my opinion you dont have tblAfstandenID..
The best way is using alias.

Answer (score 0):

If NAAM, PLAATS are member of tblInschrijvingen  table

```
string sel = "SELECT tblInschrijvingen.NAAM, tblInschrijvingen.PLAATS, tblAfstanden.AFSTAND 
            FROM tblInschrijvingen 
            INNER JOIN tblAfstanden 
                ON tblInschrijvingen.AFSTAND = tblAfstandenID.AFSTAND";
```